Añadir usuarios con todas las propiedades Identity ASP Core 8
tengo configurada la autentificacion de mi app con Identity pero me surge un problema en el endpoitn de registro, ya que no me deja registrar nombre de usuario, teléfono...solo email y contraseña.

no se si podría modificar la llamada o como deberia de poder pasar en el body el json completo.
{
  "email": "o2@gmail.com",
  "password": "Stringpas2s!",
  "phonenumber": 666555444,
  "username": "user"
}

Un saludo.

Fijate que le estas pasando por parámetro a el controlador, si le estas pasando la clase usuario por ejemplo, en el modelo tienes que tener las property con todos los datos que quieres llenar.. Si solo te nuestra esos dos puede ser que tengas incompleta la clase usuario. Agrega los campos que necesites, que deben ser iguales a los que tienes en la base de datos.

buenas, la cosa es que con Identity te lo crea todo directamente, yo no he creado ningun modelo user ni nada por el estilo, en la migracion de base de datos si que me crea username, phonenumber, email.... pero quiero modificar ese post para que admita mas campos
